# Comparing very large arrays of objects, looking for a performance boost

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using this method to compare two very large arrays of objects to create a result array.

These arrays can have from 5 to 250,000 objects, each object has 8 properties.  The properties are all strings (up to 256 chars) and integers.

It takes over 15 minutes to create the result array with 250,000 objects.

Realizing that the computer, memory, phase of the moon, etc, are all factors, I was looking for a faster/better way.

Any advice appreciated :)

```
const arr1 = [{prop1: "foo", prop2: 100},{prop1: "bar", prop2: 101}] // 250,000 objects
const arr2 = [{prop1: "foo", prop2: 50},{prop1: "bar", prop2: 51}] // 250,000 objects
let final = []

for(let left of arr1) {
        for(let right of arr2) {
            if(left.prop1 === right.prop1 && left.prop2 < right.prop2) {
                final.push(left)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the variables so your example code can run?

Comment: @Phil Am I misreading it? I don't think it does - the moment a `left` is pushed, `break` will break out of the inner loop, resulting in the outer loop running its next iteration witha a new `left`

Comment: I'm keying on a specific object (prop1 in the example), which will be unique in both arrays.

Comment: I think @sno2's comment was seeking something a little more concrete with actual `prop1` and `prop2` values

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes? Does somebody know something obvious, looks like a fairly clear question.  Insight appreciated.

Comment: The arrays can be any array of objects with properties having primitive values.  The question is more clear without the data but there you go :)

Comment: @BillKervaski the issue is that your specific use case is `O(n^2)` in complexity generally speaking which isn't overly complex, but does take thought figuring out timing in this instance as it requires data to check, which in my option could make this easier to provide a solution for

Comment: Ahh, I understand. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An approach that'll consume more memory but take less time to run will be to turn one of the arrays into an object or Map indexed by `prop1` instead. That way, rather than iterating over each element to see if it matches, just look up the <s>elements</s> element for that `prop1`.

```
const arr2ByProp1 = new Map();
for (const item of arr2) {
    arr2ByProp1.set(item.prop1, item);
}
for (const item1 of arr1) {
    const item2 = arr2ByProp1.get(item1.prop1);
    if (item2 && item1.prop2 < item2.prop2) {
        final.push(item1);
    }
}
```

You could also tweak the above to use `for(let i = 0, length = arr1.length; i < length; i++) {` instead (slightly faster, but slightly harder to read and understand at a glance). Other minor tweaks might be done, but they shouldn't have much effect in comparison to the time complexity improvement.

Having 250k items in memory to begin with is suspect, though. If they were in a database instead, it'd probably be a lot faster faster to query the database (which can find by `.prop1` and `.prop2`) to find these matches than to do the manipulations in JavaScript (which requires restructuring one of the whole data structures first, which isn't so efficient). A database may also be able to take advantage of parallel execution, unlike this particular situation of JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! It's actually in a NodeJS child process.  A local database isn't out of the question.

Comment: Using a map to create an index is a great idea btw, thank you, love learning!

Answer (score 1):

Using maps is really the way to go.  Our design was terrible.  Worked fine until we started seeing large numbers of objects.

Just iterating objects with **forEach** took 10-15 minutes ... 250,000 objects x 250,000 objects x 8 properties = 500,000,000,000 comparisons.

Using a **for...of** loop with **break** had a negligible increase in performance.

Refactored everything with maps it's down to under 5 seconds (not a type-o).

*Amazing* and *Thank You* (@CertainPerformance)!

```
const mapA = new Map() // 250,000 objects
const mapB = new Map() // 250,000 objects
let mapC   = new Map() // results

mapA.forEach((v,k) => {
    if(mapB.has(k)) {
        const o = MapA.get(k)
        if(o.prop === v.prop) {
            mapC.set(k,v)
        }
    }
})
```